# Writing a Netcat stream to file with additional text

Tags: python, linux, bash, stream, netcat

I'm trying to write a netcat stream to a local file, but I want to also annotate each streamed entry in real time with some metadata (i.e. source IP of connection), since I'll be working with multiple streams that will be writing to the same file.

For instance, the following (bash command) works fine:

```
nc 192.168.0.1 443 >> result.txt & echo -n "| Source: 192.168.0.1 | " >> result.txt
```

The problem with the code above is that it will only enter the metadata the first time. So the output looks like this:

```
Source: 192.168.0.1 | !* Connected!
X
Y
Z
```

I want the written results to look like this:

```
Source: 192.168.0.1 | !* Connected!
Source: 192.168.0.1 | X
Source: 192.168.0.1 | Y
Source: 192.168.0.1 | Z
Source: 192.168.0.2 | A     #<--Written From different netcat stream
```

Unfortunately I can't run a script to add the metadata text after netcat has completed it's job, because I need some way to identify the stream as it's being written, since multiple streams will be writing to the same file. Primarily looking for a solution in bash or python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try sed (**s**tream **ed**itor):

```
nc 192.168.0.1 443 | sed -u 's/^/Source: 192.168.0.1 | /g' >> results.txt
```

this should replace the beginning of each line `^` with the text `Source: 192.168.0.1 |`
I tested it with `tail -f some.file | sed -u 's/^/Source: 192.168.0.1 | /g'>t.txt` and got:

```
Source: 192.168.0.1 | line one
Source: 192.168.0.1 | line two
Source: 192.168.0.1 | ...
Source: 192.168.0.1 | line n
```

nb: the -u flag is to prevent sed from using buffering. This flag is only supported under linux, not mac OSX.

Comment: Thanks. This is nearly the solution needed. When I run the command nc 192.168.0.1 443 | sed 's/^/Source: 192.168.0.1 | /g' I see the results exactly as I want them (written to stdout). However when I tack on the >> results.txt it doesn't write or append to the file. I've played with redirecting output but still no luck. I'll mark this as best answer as soon as I figure out this last piece.

Comment: the problem is caused by buffering. by default every line is shown immediately if output goes to a terminal but if output goes to a file, larger chunks (4-64kB) are buffered and the file is written only once the buffer is full. See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe) maybe one of the answers there helps you.

Comment: On Linux, I found a solution, just add the `-u` flag to the sed command. I hope this helps.